# Resizing the Height of 2 blocks to always be the same depending on block with most content

Tags: theming

I have two blocks based off views on the home page of my site:

```
block-views-featured-resource-block
block-views-featured-resource2-block
```

I want them to be the same height as each other on the home page ALWAYS. They are both drawing from nodes. The nodes for each has a description field. And it varies depending on which node is set for the home page, so the length of the description for each changes regularly.

I want each block to expand in size to fit whatever contents are in the description field (might be one sentence or multiple paragraphs) for the node, and I want them both to resize based on whichever of the two has the most characters of content to the same size (one might end up having a bunch of white space below it, but that's ok.

Right now I have them set like so:

```
block-views-featured-resource-block,
block-views-featured-resource2-block {
    min-height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
```

But of course this only resizes each to fill whatever contents are in each block separately...so if the content takes up more than 350px of space one might be larger than the other. I also tried adding clear: both to the above and overflow: auto but neither of those seemed to help.

Anyone know of a way to do what I want with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of equal height jquery plugins out there.

[jquery-match-height](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) and [jQuery.equalHeights](https://github.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights) are two plugins that you can use, but there's others just google it up and you'll see for yourself.

Beyond that it's just a matter of integrating the plugin to your theme.

Answer (score 0):

We should know how you implement the parent of blocks, are these blocks sibling? If yes then I recommend you to use flex display for blocks and set the `align-items` to `stretch`. for more information visit [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your layout wraps around the two blocks, one next to the other, floated or inline:
Flexbox is a solid solution for the future. Right now, if you're targeting visitors using IE9 and below, there's another CSS feature you can use: display: table and table-cell.

```
.wrapper-name {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

block-views-featured-resource-block,
block-views-featured-resource2-block {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Javavascript has an equal heights library.

Comment: I'm not sure how my suggestion to use the matching height's library is not a solution. In fact, someone mentioned it in the same thread after me.

Comment: This is a rather generic answer: You don't link or say exactly which library you are referring.